# problem with accessing NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have the following problem:

```
int index=6;
imageView.image=[imageArray objectAtIndex:index];
NSLog(@"%@",[imageArray objectAtIndex:index]);
```

If I run this code I get (null) as an output...even though I have nicely put the images inside the array using the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"somelink"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[imageArray addObject:image];
```

I am pretty sure there are 20 images (I use an XML file and print the URL and image) and the image is fine, too. I print the values of image before putting inside the array and here's the value I get
is :

```
<UIImage: 0x5368670>
```

Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you'll need to make a new instance of the NSMutableArray... it's possible you're just calling methods on nil.

Before you start to you the imageArray, make sure you do something like:

```
imageArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
// or      = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]    if you want to "retain" it
//                                            for use in other methods
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added at least seven such objects to the array, though? Remember that `NSArray` (and friends) count from zero, not one.

Also, are you certain that the object you're adding is not null (i.e, that `dataWithContentsOfURL:` and `imageWithData:` are both succeeding)?

Comment: I am sure. I am printing the value of image when I add them and a sample output is: <UIImage: 0x5368670>